# Cakephp save data , check if belongs to authed user

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

this is how it looks:

URL: /Category/Edit/(category.id)

Controller:

loads info from category and puts it into the edit form
-> Submit form
& then you have:

$this->Category->id=$id;

$this->Category->save($this->request->data);

Because it gets the id from the url, it could easly be changed to an id that belongs another user
How do i make sure if it performs a check if the category belongs to the authed user.

Associations have been made, User->Category (one to many)

But while writing this, i might've found something, i could use beforeSave in the model
If you have any idea how this can be done better, let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. the id should be in the POSTed data, not in the submitted URL
2. use the Security Component to help keep the form from being tampered with
3. your URL example should be '/categories/edit/(category.id)'
4. build a method in your model instead of just using the default `save()` from the Controller.  In your method, you can check to make sure the owner of the category (based on the `user_id` field) matches with that of the logged in `Auth` user.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i needed :) & yes, it's /categories/